# Multiple Sustainsys saml2 configuration in Asp.Net core

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I have added multiple same2 configuration and its working fine for the first one but not working with second configuration.

I have multiple Saml configuration with different schema as below.

```
.AddSaml2("SCHM-MI", options =>
            {
                options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("SCHM-MI");
                options.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
                    new EntityId(".............."), options.SPOptions)
                {
                    MetadataLocation = "...................",
                    LoadMetadata  = true
                });
            })
           .AddSaml2("SCHM-GL",options =>
            {
                options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("SCHM-GL");
                options.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
                    new EntityId(".................."), options.SPOptions)
                {
                    MetadataLocation = "............",
                    LoadMetadata = true
                });
            });
```

This is my challenge request on login.

```
return new ChallengeResult(
                     "SCHM-GL",
                     new AuthenticationProperties
                     {
                         RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), new { returnUrl = "http://localhost:4200/callback" }),
                     });
```

This configuration is working fine for "SCHM-MI" but not working for "SCHM-GL". I am getting below error on request.

**KeyNotFoundException: No Idp with entity id "GL Entity ID" found.

Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.IdentityProviderDictionary.get_Item(EntityId entityId)**

I am using the latest version of Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.

Thanks
Imrankhan Pathan